# Opening and closing sidenav menu and issues with navbar

Tags: javascript, html

I have run in to a couple issues here. I am trying to have a locked top bar, which does work. However even though I have placed some items like the orange animated button, it appears on the bar before the text links. Secondly. I am hopeful it's possible to use the animated button as a means to also close the pop out menu from the right side of the page. Sorry if this is something really simple I'm missing here. I am still learning this stuff.

```js
    function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
 
    function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
```

```css
    body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .sidenav {
     height: 100%;
     width: 0;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     background-color: #111;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     transition: 0.5s;
     padding-top: 60px;
     }

     .sidenav a {
     padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 25px;
     color: #818181;
     display: block;
     transition: 0.3s;
     }

     .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
     color: #f1f1f1;
     }

     .sidenav .closebtn {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 25px;
     font-size: 36px;
     margin-left: 50px;
     }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
     }
     
     
    .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #577CC1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    }

    body {
    margin:0;
    background-color: #ec7c23;
 font-color: ;
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-family: arial;
    height: 1000;
 
    }

    p, td, th {
 font-size: 10pt;
 font-family: arial;
    }

    form {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

    .main {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    }



     /*animated button*/
     .container {
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
     }

    .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ec7c23;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    }

    .change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

    .change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    }
    /*END animated button*/
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
  </a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <font size=20 color=white>&nbsp;
    <b>Website</b>
  </font>


  <a href="#link">Link</a>
  <a href="#Link2">Another Link</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>

  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" >
    <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)"  >
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
<div class="navbar" style="z-index: 1000">
   <font size=20 color=white>&nbsp;
        <b>Website</b></font>

   <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:right;">
        <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    </span>
    <a href="#link">Link</a>
    <a href="#Link2">Another Link</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");
        var mySidenavWidth = document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width;

        if (mySidenavWidth === "250px")
             closeNav();
        else
             openNav();               
    }
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, that did seem to fix it. I still don't understand why even though I placed the code for the animated button before the links in the code, it still placed the links first. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: I put `float:right` for span element and moved it to top of `<a>` tags. There may be other good solutions (I am not an expert in CSS) but this change did the job ;)